# VBA - insert maxIF Formula

Tags: vba, max, formula

I'm having several sheets with data where I need to find the highest and lowest date based on criteria in other columns. 
I have defined ranged for these other columns and would like to insert formula with VBA but I keep getting a 438 error "Object doesnt support this property or method.

Any clues on what is wrong, below is the extraction of my code - when I debug it is at the formula the problem is.

```
Dim emp As Range
Set emp = Range("R5", ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
Dim epidno As Range
Set epidno = Range("B5").End(xlDown)
Dim jobtype As Range
Set jobtype = Range("D5", Selection.End(xlDown))
Dim jobdate As Range
Set jobdate = Range("J5", Selection.End(xlDown))

Dim datecell As Range
For Each datecell In Range("R5", ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp))
datecell.Offset(0, 1).Formula.Cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(IF(" + jobtype.adress + " =""TECHNICIAN"",IF(" + epidno.adress + "=RC[-1]," + jobdate.adress + ",""""),""""))"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"=MIN(IF(" + jobtype.address + " =""TECHNICIAN"",IF(" + epidno.address + "=RC[-1]," + jobdate.address + ",""""),""""))"
```

There is no `.adress` property of a range, there is a `.Address` property (2 D's, 2 S's).

Comment: Thanks, that was a bit embarrassing.  - But now I get an Object required error on the same line :/

Comment: I saw this but I thought that you may have cleared it up earlier in the code. You need to clearly assign the ranges in first part of your code to the workbsheet needed, and instantiate them properly. So first add a line after the Dim.. to say Set emp = new range (ect). Then change your current set lines to say Set emp  = Thisworkbook.Sheets('somesheetname).Range('your_range_info)